# Protecting Registers in Context Switch

Tags: process, memory, encryption

I'm working on implementing a cryptographic algorithm.

I'm using locked memory pages to keep sensitive data (such as keys and intermediate values) locked in RAM (having them never be written to swap). See [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

Is there any way I can protect the CPUs registers and other "intermediate" memory from ever being written to swap?

Here's an example of how that may happen:

The cryptographic process is running. Another process is due to be run next. A context switch occurs (at which point all of the registers are placed *somewhere* into RAM). Then, the memory page at which those registers are placed gets swapped to disk.

This is a potential problem, no?

(Am I over-engineering this?)

An obvious solution is to have the algorithm check if swap is encrypted, of course.

Comment: This is pointless. If I have physical access to the machine and you have some sensitive information located anywhere, including RAM, I can access it.

Comment: Very relevant "It is impossible to safely implement any cryptosystem providing forward secrecy in C" http://security.stackexchange.com/a/76110/35324

Comment: @9dan Thank you so much. I thought so.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Side-channel attacks aside. This question is mainly concerned with forward secrecy as 9dan points out.